# Point URL to different IP, A record

Tags: heroku, dns, ip, a-records

Example

Let's say we have a domain www.example.com.

This domain points to Heroku and we have functional website.

```
example.herokuapp.com
www.example.com
```

When we load the website

```
www.example.com
```

our website works and succesfully loading App on Heroku. Let's say it is running a Django framework (Python Environment)

There is another website that has different IP and is built in Ruby Rails for example and is running on different host provider.

If we load the website www.example.com, we are on the homepage, we can easily browse different pages like about, photos, videos etc.

Is there a possibility if I type

```
www.example.com/store/
```

that it would load that ruby rails website?

Let's remove possibilty moving the app from different provider to heroku or any other provider that www.example.com is on (or precisly were example.com points to in DNS).

Is it possible to map it somehow or point it in DNS to make it work like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer, you could use a 301 redirect from /store/ to the other site, or a subdomain, like store.example.com. For more information, read up on DNS A records, as you suspected! Good luck!

Comment: I understand that part how to do 301 that is what I was trying to avoid. I do not need to use 301 in the menu I would just add a link www.otherprovider.com/store/ and it would work, my point is to stay is on the main domain do like example.com/store/gear/, example.com/store/gear/skis/ etc...but thank you for quick answer...

Comment: Without getting into a proxy server or router, while maintaining sessions across multiple servers / environments, this isn't possible. I've done something similar when migrating sites: we have a router which routes some traffic to Django, some to legacy code. We had to develop systems to authenticate users on both code bases during login / logout, and configure the router by directory to separate code bases. It isn't trivial at all to do.

Comment: I thought so, guess only the step is having still the subdomain store.example.com, I would like to put it under main domain for SEO purposes, thank you for your input